# Best practice for creating inline anchor tags

Tags: css

So generally if i have an anchor list, do you prefix it so it wont get accidently styled by the css?

```
<ul class="inline-list">
<li><a href="#list1">List 1 </a></li>
<li><a href="#list2">List 2</a></li>

</ul>

<h2 id="list1">List 1 Heading</h2>
```

If list1 is speciifed in my global css, it will get a styling.  Any best practice for this?

Comment: not clear what you want... you want to apply list1 css to <a> tag? CSS work on class and on ID not on href attribute (if not pseudo css ).

Comment: I did not fully understand your question but I will answer according to what I understood. Actually I use list inside of a **nav** tag, which is built-in HTML5. So to style it, I will use this nav ul{ ----- }  hence it won't get affected by any other list.

Comment: Many people consider targeting `id`s with css a bad practice, partially because of the high specifity, but of course, your problem supports this, too.